# metastore_db doesn't get created with apache spark 2.2.1 in windows 7

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want read CSV files using latest `Apache Spark Version i.e 2.2.1` in `Windows 7 via cmd` but unable to do so because there is some problem with the `metastore_db`. I tried below steps:

```
1. spark-shell --packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.11:1.5.0 //Since my scala 
                                                              // version is 2.11  
 2. val df = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").option("mode", "DROPMALFORMED").load("file:///D:/ResourceData.csv")// As //in latest versions we use SparkSession variable i.e spark instead of //sqlContext variable
```

but it throws me below error:

```
  Caused by: org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException: Failed to start database 'metastore_db' with class loader o
.spark.sql.hive.client.IsolatedClientLoader  

Caused by: org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException: Another instance of Derby may have already booted the database
```

I am able to read csv in 1.6 version but I want to do it in latest version. Can anyone help me with this?? I am stuck since many days .

Comment: Do you have any other Spark application (incl. `spark-shell`) up and running? Can you edit your question and add the entire stack trace?

Comment: I dont have any other spark application running and its a long stacktrace. I cannot put it here so i just figured out the main cause line from the stacktrace

Comment: BTW, you don't need `com.databricks:spark-csv_2.11:1.5.0` since it's part of Spark 2.x already. Remove it to have less to worry about.

Comment: tried without using databricks package but still getting the same error. I have updated my question Let me know if any additional information is required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Open Spark Shell**

```
spark-shell
```

**Pass Spark Context through SQLContext and assign it to sqlContext Variable**

```
 val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc) // As Spark context available as 'sc'
```

**Read the CSV file as per your requirement**

```
val bhaskar = sqlContext.read.format("csv")
  .option("header", "true")
  .option("inferSchema", "true")
  .load("/home/burdwan/Desktop/bhaskar.csv") // Use wildcard, with * we will be able to import multiple csv files in a single load ...Desktop/*.csv
```

**Collect the RDDs and Print**

```
bhaskar.collect.foreach(println)
```

**Output**

```
_a1 _a2     Cn      clr clarity depth   aprx price  x       y       z
1   0.23    Ideal   E   SI2     61.5    55   326    3.95    3.98    2.43
2   0.21    Premium E   SI1     59.8    61   326    3.89    3.84    2.31
3   0.23    Good    E   VS1     56.9    65   327    4.05    4.07    2.31
4   0.29    Premium I   VS2     62.4    58   334    4.2     4.23    2.63
5   0.31    Good    J   SI2     63.3    58   335    4.34    4.35    2.75
6   0.24    Good    J   VVS2    63      57   336    3.94    3.96    2.48
```

Comment: I tried val bhaskar = sqlContext.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").option("inferSchema", "true").load("D:/SampleDemand") but throws same error in windows.

Comment: I am able to process it in linux using SparkSession variable i.e spark

Comment: Try to run your Command Prompt in Windows in Administrative Privilege and after that Run `spark-shell`

Answer (score 0):

Finally even this also worked only in linux based O.S. Download apache spark from the official documentation and set it up using [this](https://www.dezyre.com/apache-spark-tutorial/apache-spark-installation-tutorial) link. Just verify whether you are able to invoke `spark-shell`. Now enjoy loading and performing actions with any type of file with the latest spark version. I don't know why its not working on windows even though I am running it for the first time.